Can this hook up be possible?
I'm  installing a northflo 50000 btu heat pump it say runs at 12 amps..@)  20 amp breaker at main panel  , can i replace my 40 gfi breaker in spa pack with a 20 amp?

So the spa is not being used anymore?  Down sizing breakers or up sizing wires is usually allowed.

I'm adding a pool heat pump

You can replace the 40 amp breaker with a 20 amp breaker, if you are not using the 40 amp circuit(spa) anymore.
